# OneDRIVE SDK - Python

Tags: python, onedrive

Задача следующая:

> Нужно бэкапить winzip-ом файл бд с разбивкой на тома и сохранять ее в
>   аккаунте OneDrive.

---

Решил использоваться библиотеку [onedrive-sdk-python](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python). После ее скачивания и установки начал предпринимать попытки коннекта к облаку.

Какие разрешения нужно устанавливать в настройках "Моего приложения"?

Пока нашел информацию только на оф сайте, но немного непонятно, если я не использую какой либо сервер, какое значение мне использовать в запросе.

```
auth_url = client.auth_provider.get_auth_url(redirect_uri)
code = GetAuthCodeServer.get_auth_code(auth_url, redirect_uri)
```

Что можно указать в redirect_uri? Как я понял, он должен совпадать с значением в личном кабинете. В принципе среда разработки не важна

Подскажите пожалуйста или поделитесь материалом по onedrive api.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81264/discussion-on-question-by---onedrive-sdk-python).